# Paste data from another worksheet into next row in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I need to open a dialog box and select a workbook. Then copy the data placed in that workbook (which has only 1 sheet with same name all the time).

I want to do the process for many workbooks by using a loop for vbyesno.

This is the only part which is not working because I want to paste data under Range("a14"), then loop and then paste under the data pasted in a14.

Below is the macro which is being called from another macro.

```
Sub prompt()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Target_Path As Range
    d = MsgBox("Add record?", vbYesNoCancel + vbInformation)
    If d = vbNo Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("a13").value = "No data Found"
        ActiveSheet.Range("a13").Font.Bold = True
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    ElseIf d = vbCancel Then
        Sheets("MPSA").Delete
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    ElseIf d = vbYes Then
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("a14").value = "NAME"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("b14").value = "NUMBER"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("c14").value = "AGR NUMBER"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("d14").value = "ENTITY NAME"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("e14").value = "GROUP"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("f14").value = "DELIVERABLE"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("g14").value = "DELIVERAB"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("h14").value = "IS COMPON"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("i14").value = "PACKAGE"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("j14").value = "ORDERS"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("k14").value = "LICNTITY"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("l14").value = "QUANTITY"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("m14").value = "ORDERANUMBER"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("n14").value = "ORDERAM NAME"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("o14").value = "PAC NUMBER"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("p14").value = "PACKAGAME"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("q14").value = "ITTION"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("r14").value = "LICENSE TYPE"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("s14").value = "ITEM VERSION"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("t14").value = "REAGE"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("u14").value = "CLIIT"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("v14").value = "LICEAME"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("w14").value = "ASSATE"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("x14").value = "ASSTE"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("y14").value = "ENTITTUS"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("z14").value = "ASSGORY"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("aa14").value = "PURCHAYPE"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("ab14").value = "BILLTHOD"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("ac14").value = "SALETER"
        Cells.Columns.AutoFit
        Target_Path = Application.GetOpenFilename
        Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Target_Path)
        Set Source_Workbook = ThisWorkbook

        Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
        Target_Workbook.Close
        Source_Workbook.Sheets("MPSA").Range("a14").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial = Target_Data
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that this code *works* for only one iteration?

Comment: If I understand correctly: this is the code to paste a range from one worksheet to another. You want SO to write the code that will call up a dialogue box to highlight desired workbooks, amend and call this pasting code to add range data at the bottom of the sheet, and then iterate that code until the user clicks 'stop'. That's asking an awful lot of a volunteer don't you think? Have a go at the code yourself and we'll help you where you get stuck. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to propose a mechanism to achieve the loop, supposing that your current code is somewhere *near* what you want to achieve. But I found many mistakes so I had to refactor it, hopefully it will get you a step further.

The following code will continue looping until user presses `Cancel` in the file dialog box:

```
Sub prompt()
    Dim d As VbMsgBoxResult: d = MsgBox("Add record?", vbYesNoCancel + vbInformation)
    If d = vbNo Then
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("a13").value = "No data Found"
        Sheets("MPSA").Range("a13").Font.Bold = True
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If d = vbCancel Then
        Sheets("MPSA").Delete
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo Cleanup
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False: Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("MPSA").Range("a14:ac14").value = Array( _
    "NAME", "NUMBER", "AGR NUMBER", "ENTITY NAME", "GROUP", "DELIVERABLE", "DELIVERAB", "IS COMPON", _
    "PACKAGE", "ORDERS", "LICNTITY", "QUANTITY", "ORDERANUMBER", "ORDERAM NAME", "PAC NUMBER", "PACKAGAME", _
    "ITTION", "LICENSE TYPE", "ITEM VERSION", "REAGE", "CLIIT", "LICEAME", "ASSATE", "ASSTE", _
    "ENTITTUS", "ASSGORY", "PURCHAYPE", "BILLTHOD", "SALETER")

    Sheets("MPSA").Columns.AutoFit
    Dim Target_Path: Target_Path = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Do While Target_Path <> False ' <-- loop until user cancels
        Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook: Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Target_Path)
        Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MPSA").Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Target_Workbook.Close False
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        Target_Path = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Loop
Cleanup:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Something went wrong: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True: Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,
Your code work fine but there is something different which i need. I'll explain

Comment: Dear @Ashwendra, I think we need to proceed a bit differently, one by one :). As I iunderstand the code above provides a solution but you need to change the flow, I propose that you close this question and ask a new one that corresponds exactly to the changes needed. Surely I as well as many others will be glad to help.

Comment: Hello @A.S.H , website is not allowing me to ask another question.
Can you pls help me with this.... In your code...I need to delete first row everytime i chose a new sheet to copy data from. can you help me with this particular line

Comment: Try `Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Copy _`

Comment: Man, you're a legend ! :) Will ask a different question and will try to tag you specially :D
I'll have to wait for 2 days to ask another question